# Combining fade function and convert to a flac file

Tags: linux, sox, libsox

I'm using linux trying to fade and convert an audio file to flac see command below

```
sox /tmp/audio1.wav /tmp/audio2.flac fade h 0:60 0 0:60
```

How can I add the **flac option "-b 16"** to the line above

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bits-per-sample option goes before the output file, i.e.:

```
sox infile -b 16 outfile
```

Are you sure you want the fade in/out over 60 seconds?

As an illustration, here is a working example that fades in over .05 seconds at the beginning and end of a sweep:

```
sox -n -d synth 1 sine 10k-1k fade h .05 0 gain -20
```

Volume adjusted to avoid ear damage.

You can visualize the signal with the spectrogram effect, e.g.:

```
sox -n -d synth 1 sine 10k-1k fade h .05 0 gain -20 spectrogram -o specgram.png
```

Answer (score 1):

in case someone needs this the syntax it's

```
sox /tmp/infile.wav -b 16 /tmp/outfile.flac fade h 0:60 0 0:60
```

this will output a 16bit flac file with 60 second fade in and 60 second fade out

Comment: In the interest of brevity you can omit the fade-out length when it is the same as the fade-in length, so `fade h 60 0` would be sufficient.